# ESP 01: Sketch uploading but not running

Tags: esp8266, programming

I have this ESP8266 I've been trying to get to work with a USB to TTL converter. I can flash the code through the Arduino IDE to the ESP8266 and it supposedly succeeds, but the ESP8266 isn't running the code. If I try to make a Wi-Fi network (to create a webserver), it won't appear, and if I try to print something to the serial log, it won't appear. Here is a Fritzing model of my circuit:

[image: fritzing model of my circuit]

(Note: The pins of my TTL converter are actually GND, CTS, 3V3, TX, RX, and DTR. I wish I could change the text of the Fritzing part I downloaded, but it is what it is.)

Here are the options in the Arduino IDE I used:

[image]

Note: I saw [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/413918/esp8266-not-running-uploaded-arduino-sketch), but the answer only made it worse (wouldn't upload at all), so I am asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ESP8266 has different boot modes. i.e.

[image]

The ESP-01 module will keep booting into uart programming mode if gpio-0 is connected to GND. You can verify this by taking a look at the serial monitor output while powering up or resetting the esp8266.

In order to fix this, after the code is uploaded, you need to connect gpio-0 to 3V3 and reset the esp8266 in order to see the code running on the module.